# c# ReportViewer Export

Tags: c#, export, reportviewer

In `ReportView` I want to *export* to the following formats: .docx, .pdf, or .xlsx

Export to .pdf:

```cs
reportViewer.ExportDialog(_reportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions()[3]);
```

Export to .docx:

```cs
reportViewer.ExportDialog(_reportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions()[5]);
```

Export to .xlsx:

```cs
reportViewer.ExportDialog(_reportViewer.LocalReport.ListRenderingExtensions()[1]);
```

But at first I have to choose a format for saving. 
I want at first to open ***SaveFileDialog*** and in it to choose a format for saving

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I came up with:

```cs
string _sSuggestedName = String.Empty;

byte[] byteViewerPDF = _reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");  
byte[] byteViewerExcel = _reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel");  
byte[] byteViewerWord = _reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("Word");

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf| Doc files
(*.doc)|*.doc| Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls";

if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
{

  FileStream newFile = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create);

  if (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex == 1)
  {
    newFile.Write(byteViewerPDF, 0, byteViewerPDF.Length);
    newFile.Close();
  }
  else
    if (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex == 2)
    {
      newFile.Write(byteViewerWord, 0, byteViewerWord.Length);
      newFile.Close();
    }
  else
    if (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex == 3)
    {
      newFile.Write(byteViewerExcel, 0, byteViewerExcel.Length);
      newFile.Close();
    }

}
```