# Customize Report Viewer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, export, reportviewer

I used `Report Viewer` in my winforms applications to generate my reports. 
I need to customize it to limit the target export type to **Excel** and **Word** type ie avoid the **PDF** export.

How can I accomplish this task?Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953524/c-sharp-reportviewer-export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this snippet in the `ReportExport` event

```
 private void reportViewer1_ReportExport(object sender, ReportExportEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Extension.Name.ToLower() == "pdf")
            {

                reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
        }
```

It works fine